# Firebase Filter Data by Get

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, get

I am newbe at firebase and want filter the following Data

```
Adresse
{
    "-Kx92hLOJ_rRCxOIlmn7": {
    "Name": "Käppeler",
    "Nr": "1026",
    "Ort": "-",
    "STRASSE": "-",
    "Vorname": "Simon"
},
"-Kx92mv2Hk5lr7Ay7X9h": {
    "Name": "Müller",
    "Nr": "1040",
    "Ort": "-",
    "STRASSE": "-",
    "Vorname": "Madlene"
}
```

}

I want filter only the dataset with the Nr 1040
For this i try to use the follow Get command at Postman:

```
 https://<my database>.firebaseio.com/Adresse.json?orderBy="Nr"&equalTo="1040"
```

I try all:

```
?orderBy="Nr"&startAt=1040&print=pretty
?orderBy="Adress/Nr"&startAt=1040&print=pretty
?orderBy="$key"&startAt="10"&endAt="40"&print=pretty
```

but nothing work. can anyone help me?

Comment: Works for me: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/46906936.json?orderBy=%22Nr%22&equalTo=%221040%22

Answer (score 0):

You must use roles for search. Like this;

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
     ".write": true,
     "Adresse": {  
          ".indexOn": ["Name","Nr"] 
    }
  }
}
```

after you can use like this:

```
https://<my database>.firebaseio.com/Adresse.json?orderBy="Nr"&startAt=1040&limitToFirst=1
```

Comment: Is there a way to compare 2 fields like in SQL. "where Nr =1040 and line = 1" for orderBy="Nr"&equalTo="1040"